# .less file is not working in angularjs application

Tags: angularjs

I am using `.less` file in my `angularjs` application.when I start the application it gives me an error of `file not found(404)` with path.I don't know what is happening. i have throughly checked my path and it is correct.but still it is throwing exception.

I didn't find any solution yet.kindly help me.

thanks

Comment: can anybody help me? please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to webconfig

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
</staticContent >
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: i am using netbeans for angularjs code.i am not using visual studio.